# JFrame not showing content, only blank white box

Tags: java, swing

So I am working on a school project that implements JFrame to create a cityscape. After changing on of the constructor methods to a class, all that shows up is a white box.

```
public CityscapeComponent(int amountStars)
{
    numberOfStars = amountStars;
}

/**
 * This method is invoked by the Java Run-Time whenever the component needs to be redrawn.
 * It does not need to be invoked explicitly.
 *
 */
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;




    Background base = new Background(50);
    Stars starDots = new Stars(100, 5, 5);
    Bridge suspBridge = new Bridge(100);
    Buildings skyscrapers = new Buildings(200);
    Grid mainGrid = new Grid();



    base.draw(g2);
    starDots.draw(g2);
    suspBridge.draw(g2);
    skyscrapers.draw(g2);
    mainGrid.draw(g2);
}
```

}

So it was previously working, but now it gives me no syntax errors. And yes I have everything properly imported and all, had to omit some of the code to avoid confusion.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: looks like Background, Stars, Bridge, Buildings, Grid are customized classes all with a draw method. Could you provide an example on how they look like?

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) , so we can help you.

Comment: Add @Override above your paintComponent method and make sure you're calling super.paintComponet before you do any custom painting

Comment: *"..implements JFrame.."*  A frame, huh?  Change `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)..` to `@Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) ..`.  If you cannot work it out from the compiler message, post an MCVE as advised earlier..